# Using Lua to format 0 seconds as 00:00:00

Tags: time, lua, duration

I'm trying to format a duration (in seconds) as a time and I'm getting results indicating that I'm supposed to account for an epoch somewhere. I expected `os.date("%X", 0)` to produce "00:00:00" but it is returning "20:00:00" as well as a date value of "12/31/69" (I don't need a calendar date though).

Is there a standard way of getting a time duration string that causes 0 seconds to produce a clock representing a total of zero seconds? I can't seem to find an example anywhere of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In most systems (ie, POSIX), `os.date("%X",0)` gives you the time of the epoch, which is  00:00:00 (Coordinated Universal Time, UTC), 1 January 1970.
You get `20:00:00` because you're in a different time zone.

To force UTC instead of your time zone, start the format with `!`. This is mentioned in the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-os.date).

So, use `os.date("!%X",0)` to get `00:00:00` as desired. It'll work with any number of seconds less than a day (86400). For instance, `os.date("!%X",70)` gives `00:01:10`: 1 minute and 10 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Lua does not have a vast standard library:

```
string.format("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", s/(60*60), s/60%60, s%60)
```

Comment: This works fine after fixing the order of operations: s/(60*60)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't test it. Also I missed the modulus on the minutes.

Comment: `os.date` can do it. See my answer.

Comment: Tempting but... no. Half of the time %d will round numbers up, which is no good. E.g. 90 sceonds shows as "00:02:30" instead of "00:01:30"

Comment: This no longer works in Lua 5.3.x, since `%d` requires integer as its input. Of course, you can always workaround that by wrapping in `math.floor`.