# How to make a Hour:Minute:Seconds counter using os.clock?

Tags: math, lua

Mostly a math problem, I need a session counter in the HH:MM:SS format (will be used in a HUD)

Something like this :

```
local StartSession = os.clock()

local h = (os.clock() - StartSession)/3600
local m = ??
local s = ??

local Counter = h..":"..m..":"..s
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `os.time()`, which returns the current time, instead of `os.clock()`, which returns CPU time since Lua started:

```
local StartSession = os.time()
-- some time later ...
local Counter = os.date("!%X", os.difftime(os.time(),StartSession))
```

This will work as long as the elapsed time is less than a day.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474312/using-lua-to-format-0-seconds-as-000000/17480764.

Comment: Could you show me how to do using only os.date? I don't necessairly need to use os.clock just didnt think of it