# Can I use os.date to convert seconds to time format?

Tags: lua

I need a simple function to convert seconds into a time string that humans can read to represent the countdown. I can get the results what I need through very intuitive mathematical calculations, but not elegant enough.

Then I noticed that there is a function named os.date, but I can't get the result I want, what is wrong with my calling, here is my code:

```lua
#!usr/bin/env lua

local function getDate1(sec)
    local days = math.floor(sec / 86400)
    local hours = math.floor((sec % 86400) / 3600)
    local minutes = math.floor((sec % 3600) / 60)
    local seconds = math.floor(sec % 60)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds
end

local function getDate2(sec)
    local date = os.date("*t", sec)
    return date["day"], date["hour"], date["min"], date["sec"]
end

local function printDate(d, h, m, s)
    print(string.format("%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", d, h, m, s))
end

function main()
    printDate(getDate1(999999))
    printDate(getDate2(999999))
end

main()
```

> 11 13:46:39
>
> 12 21:46:39

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480764/107090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function getDate2(sec)
    local date = os.date("!*t", sec)
    return date["day"]-1, date["hour"], date["min"], date["sec"]
end
```

Comment: Why day - 1? and ! mean? I can't find it in the documentation

Comment: See [Doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.date) about `!`. The `day - 1` is because of 0-th day is `January 1`